# can i solve odes with complex coefficients in matlab?

Tags: matlab, ode, coefficients

I am solving system of Odes with complex coefficients using standard ode45 method ,but not getting desired results . 
below is my M.file

```
function dy=tarak(t,y)

g0=.1;

t0=200;

s=90;

g=g0*exp(-((t-t0)/s).^2);

G=sqrt(10);

dy=zeros(5,1);

dy(1)=-2*2*y(1)+1i*G*conj(y(3))+1i*g*conj(y(4))-1i*G*y(3)-1i*conj(g)*y(4);

dy(2)=2*y(1)+1i*G*y(3)-1i*G*conj(y(3));

dy(3)=-2*y(3)+1i*G*y(2)+1i*g*conj(y(5))-1i*G*y(1);

dy(4)=-2*y(4)+1i*G*y(5)+1i*g*(1-y(1)-y(2))-1i*g*y(1);

dy(5)=1i*G*y(4)-1i*g*conj(y(3));
```

and command 
t=0:500;

> [T,Y] = ode45(@tarak,t,[0 0 0 0 0 ]);

In results i am getting negative values for some  Y(1) and y(2) . but it should be always positive

is there any fault in my approach ?

Thanks

Comment: please put your current result and expected result for users to understand the problem better.

Comment: ok ,i am editing above post

Answer (score 2):

If you were using google, you would find posts like

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102582-do-the-ode-functions-from-matlab-i-e-ode23-ode24-handle-complex-numbers-properly

- " Answer by MathWorks Support Team on 26 Jul 2010: The ODE solvers in MATLAB 5 (R12) and later releases properly handle complex valued systems."

Comment: Thanks for link Lutzl ,so i need to check my equations as it says there are no issues with complex coefficients for ode solvers